# Access 2007 Locking Issue - Attachments being overwritten

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, attachment

We're currently running into an issue with an Access 2007 database for a client.  They've got Excel 2007 documents attached to records within the database.  Whenever changes to the document are made, they are overwriting each other, and we're not sure exactly why.  This is happening with different records, and all of the attached documents are named differently.  We've tried adjusting the different locking schemes, but this doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

Any ideas?  Are we missing something?

Comment: this is not clear enough, are attached document overwriting other attached document ? How are the change made : detail the procedure.

Comment: And Access is a very bad fit for multi-user database anyway, as it remains a "personal database", and a very bad one I might add.

Comment: @Remou access offers little or no security beyond filesystem ACL, and is prone to corruption, especially with binary fields, or over network with higher latency than a wired LAN. As a personal database it is nice but beyond (more than 1 user) it does not offer enough facilities for business use. There are better free solutions (the downside being that you must code the frontend separately).

Comment: @dvhh Small companies cannot always afford an IT section and programming services, which nearly all the alternatives require, and not all such companies require industrial strength security. Access works very well in the area it is designed for, which includes up to about 30 users. I have used Access for quite a number of years in such areas and only experienced a severe problem once, and all the data was recovered undamaged, without resort to a backup and without major effort.

Comment: Are these OLE fields or are these the new Attachment fields?

Comment: That's likely why the locking doesn't work, because the attachment data is actually not stored in the main record, but in another table that is hidden and linked with another hidden table. In other words, it's an N:N join structure, just with the structure hidden from you and accessible only via DAO. I would recommend against using the attachment data type except where you are integrating with Sharepoint and you need it for that purpose. With all other apps, you would create the other tables explicitly so you have full control over editing. I'd also recommend against OLE fields entirely.

Answer (score 0):

the attached documents are overwriting other  attached documents the key is they are open at the same time by different users.

They are making the changes using excel saving them to a temp folder and then access saves the documents through its interface. This is pretty standard.

@dvhh Please refrain from access bashing.  I agree access sucks. This is a system the client already had in place that I need to get working or give a reasonable response to why this particular piece is not working and can not be fixed.

@Remou  access is limited there are better options out their Access has its place and its uses for business please leave it at that.

Comment: "Better options" -- that ignores the question "for what?" Whether or not Access is appropriate depends on the task at hand.